# How can I hide the parameters of this URL?

Tags: html, ajax, dojo

I have a ajax call in my javascript and its returning some response as json and redirecting the json values to another jsp page.. in the redirected jsp page, am getting the whole json in the url tab.. how to avoid that...
here is my ajax call in js file...

```
var cols="PRIORITY,USER_ID,PARTICIPANT_TYPE,CREATION_DATE,ASSIGN_TO_USER_DATE,START_WORK_DATE,DUE_DATE,OPERATION,ORDER_VK,SENDER_TYPE,SENDER_ID,ORDER_ID,FLAGS";
    var ioArgs = {
                                                        url: "./DynamicDBServlet",
                                                        content: { TABLE_NAME:'CWPWORKLIST',WHERE_CONDN:cond,COLUMNS:cols}, 
                                                        handleAs: "json",
                                                        load: function(response) {
                                                        alert("new  "+new String(response));
                                                            window.location.href = "worklist.jsp?PRIORITY="+response;
                                                        },
                                                        error: function(error) {
                                                            alert("An unexpected error occurred: " + error);
                                                        }
                                                };
```

Comment: use `POST` instead of `GET` on `AJAX Request`

Comment: alert("new  "+new String(response)); =>  alert("new  "+new String(response.url));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
window.location.href = "worklist.jsp?PRIORITY="+response;
```

with:

```
openWindowWithPost("worklist.jsp",'height=300px,width=300px,top=200px,left=500px,scrollbars=no,sizable=yes,toolbar=no,statusbar=no','title',param);
```

and then have the below function:

```
function openWindowWithPost(url, windowoption, name, params)
{
         var form = document.createElement("form");
         form.setAttribute("method", "post");
         form.setAttribute("action", url);
         form.setAttribute("target", name);
         var input = document.createElement('input');
         input.type = 'hidden';
         input.name = "PARAM";
         input.value = params;
         form.appendChild(input);
         /*for (var i in params) {
             if (params.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                 var input = document.createElement('input');
                 input.type = 'hidden';
                 input.name = i;
                 input.value = params[i];
                 form.appendChild(input);
             }
         }*/
         document.body.appendChild(form);
         window.open(url, name, windowoption);
         //alert("inside openpost");
         form.submit();
         document.body.removeChild(form);
 }
```

and read the values to worklist.jsp using the name PARAM......

Answer (score 1):

You are now using GET to send your `PRIORITY` variable. Use POST!

You will have to create a form consisting of a single hidden input, put response in the value attribute of said input and submit the form having it's action point to your worklist.jsp.

Comment: already am using xhrPost only... var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(ioArgs);

Comment: @Gung Foo is right: It's not about your AJAX request, but about your window.location.href. This results in a GET request. You need to replace *this* with the solution Gung Foo described, then you do not have the parameters in the URL any more.

Comment: @Gung Foo: still am not clear.. am sorry.. my jsp page does not contain form tag!!

Comment: that is why you should add one. `window.location.href = "worklist.jsp?PRIORITY="+response;` this line is a GET request.